# How do I use instantiate Vkeyboard and MDDropdownmenu on KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

In the code below: I want to be able to get input from the keyboard module on KivyMD and my dropdown box to display. None of them are working. I am trying to figure out as other modules have been working properly.From what I understand that I cannot get input from the keyboard because it is in a different data type. How would I convert it to where I could draw input from it for my backend?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.vkeyboard import VKeyboard
Window.size = (300, 500)
Window.keyboard_anim_args = {'d':.2,'t': 'in_out_expo'}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:
    UploadScreen:
        

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    
    MDTextField:
        id : username
        hint_text: "Enter Username"
        helper_text: "or click on forgot username"
        #helper_text_mode: "persistent"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        icon_right: "account"
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint_x:None    
        width:250
        mode : "rectangle"   
    VKeyboard:
        Layout: 'Numeric.json'
    MDDropdownmenu:    
        values: ["Los Angeles","Las Vegas","New York"]
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Profile'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Upload'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'upload'    
<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'profile'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Welcome Oliver'
        halign: 'center'
    
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'    

<UploadScreen>:
    name: 'upload'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'upload daw ek ek'
        halign: 'center'
    
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'    
                        
"""


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ProfileScreen(Screen):

    pass


class UploadScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='profile'))
sm.add_widget(UploadScreen(name='upload'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen0 = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen0

        keyboard = VKeyboard()


DemoApp().run()
```

The error is included here:

```
File "C:/Users/63917/PycharmProjects/kivymd/text_input.py", line 95, in <module>
     DemoApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/Users/63917/PycharmProjects/kivymd/text_input.py", line 90, in build
     screen0 = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 401, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 510, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "C:\Users\63917\PycharmProjects\kivymd\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 584, in parse_level
     'Invalid data after declaration')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 23:
 ...
      21:        mode : "rectangle"   
      22:    VKeyboard:
 >>   23:        Layout: 'Numeric.json'
      24:    MDDropdownmenu:    
      25:        values: ["Los Angeles","Las Vegas","New York"]
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration
```

Comment: `Layout` should not be capitalized.